# Does windows7 log the files I've recycled?

Tags: logging, recycle-bin

Over the past week or so I've recycled and then deleted a lot of photos. I realize now that I would like to know the number of photos I've deleted. Is there any way to do this? Is there a log file showing a list of the files sent to the recycling bin? I am running windows 7.
Thank you.

Comment: I don't think there is straight forward way to do this. But if you haven't been messing too much with you hard drive, there's a good chance you can use a data recovery tool(eg. recuva) to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks, I did consider that but since I am just curious about the number I've deleted and I don't actually need to keep the files I am not sure it would be worth using recovery software. I was hoping Windows somehow tracked it. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

No, there is no such log file.

You could take a look at what is in the recycle bin right now and count the photos. There is a script on [StackOverflow: Listing files in recycle bin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716521/listing-files-in-recycle-bin) that you could use for that.

Comment: I've been emptying the recycle bin and permanently deleting the files so there is currently nothing in the bin to count. Thank you.